# Get browser Accept-Language header value for a fetch request

Tags: javascript, localization, http-accept-language

I just realized that `fetch` does not send `Accept-Language` header by default, therefore I plan to add that. However, I haven't come across any way to get the string that the browser should generate.

For example, in my browser, all normal requests have a nice Accept-Language value:

> en-US,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8,vi;q=0.7,la;q=0.6

My problem can be solved by either option:

- Is there a declaration that tell browser to include Accept-Language
  header with `fetch`?
- Is there a way to get that string instead of generate it from
  `navigator.languages`? Currently I am using this method, but I made
  it myself, and not sure if it's overkill/bad. I would prefer to use a
  built in way if possible.

```
var getAcceptLanguageValue = () => {
    // Assume there are less than 10 languages
    let q = 1;

    return navigator.languages
        .slice(0, 10)
        .map(l => `${l};q=0.${10-q++}`)
        .join(",");
};
```

The result I get is not identical obviously:

> en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7,vi;q=0.6,la;q=0.5

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Noitidart unfortunately no, I have been using the workaround since.

Comment: Thanks very much for the fast reply!! I'm not even sure of the rules on this, I'm trying to put `window.navigator.languages` will use your workaround too.